# How can we change the (a1|a2|a3 b1|b2|b3) to ((a1,a2,a3),(b1,b2,b3)) in spark scala

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Convert the (a1|a2|a3 b1|b2|b3) to ((a1,a2,a3),(b1,b2,b3)) in spark scala.

Comment: you need add more context to the question about the input data and what code have you tried.

Comment: what is this ```(a1|a2|a3 b1|b2|b3)``` is it string ??

Comment: @QuickSilver it is up to us how we can create this .. I have this input data a1|a2|a3 b1|b2|b3 and need to convert it to ((a1,a2,a3),(b1,b2,b3)).

Comment: @Srinivas yes it is string.

Comment: strings means - "a1|a2|a3", "b1|b2|b3" or "a1|a2|a3 b1|b2|b3" ? Please add clear input & expected output .. if you add () .. it has different meaning.

Comment: @Srinivas  this is the input (a1|a2|a3 b1|b2|b3) and output will be ((a1,a2,a3),(b1,b2,b3)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Split your String to form a Seq
2. Convert Seq to DataFrame
3. Append the String with the appropriate prefix `(` and postfix `)`
4. Map row => String
5. Collect the Dataframe as list
6. Concatenate the list with `,` and prefix `(` and postfix `)`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object ParseAString {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = Constant.getSparkSess
    import spark.implicits._
    val inputStr = "a1|a2|a3 b1|b2|b3".split(" ").toSeq.toDF

    val result = inputStr
      .select( concat(lit("("),regexp_replace($"value","\\|",","),lit(")") ) )
      .map(row => {
        row.getString(0)
      })
      .collect().mkString(",")
    println(s"(${result})")

  }

}
```

Comment: Thanku so much for the answer. I have one doubt. why we use getString(0).

Comment: Type casting from rows to String where `getString` make sure we get value in string and `getString(0)` make sure we get string value of the first column, in our case its the first and only column

Comment: i think it converts dataframe to dataset[string]. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Thats what map function does and btw both are same refer below quote,
"
DataFrame- In dataframe data is organized into named columns. Basically, it is as same as a table in a relational database. whereas, DataSets- As we know, it is an extension of dataframe API, which provides the functionality of type-safe, object-oriented programming interface of the RDD API."

Comment: val input = "abc,cd3,dge,gdd4".split(",").toSeq.toDF().rdd.map(s=>s.getString(0).split(",").filter(s=>s.matches(".*\\d.*")))
Still do not know why we used getString(0) here.

Comment: First we convert to Seq -> DF -> rdd
Don't know why we did this here